# Internal Server Error when trying to activate/deactivate the Sendcloud plugin

Tags: updates

when trying to update to v6.5.2.1., activate/deactivate a plugin, I get an error message:
`Internal Server Error Unable to set visibility for file asset-manifest.json. chmod(): Operation not permitted.` Could you please advise on how to approach this issue? Thank you in advance